# Functional reactive programming with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a normal Backbone.Collection made up of user models. The models and the collection are nothing special.

When I clear out the Backbone collection, by calling destroy on each of the models, another reference in my program to one of the destroyed models seems to remain intact. My question is - how can I write my JS program so that when all of the models in the user collection get destroyed, the reference in appState.currentUser (see below) gets set to null. Do I need to use something fancy like an event or 'functional reactive programming' or should JavaScript be able to take care of this out-of-the-box? Right now, the appState.currentUser variable does not "become null" when I clear out all of the models, even though appState.currentUser references one of the Backbone user models (!)

I have this simple singleton data structure that represents the state of the app - the logged-in user, the environment, etc:

```
define('appState',function() {

    var appState = {

        currentUser: null,
        authorized: null,
        hasSession: null,
        env: null

    };

    return {
        value: appState,
        get: function(val){
            return appState[val];
        },
        set: function(prop,val){
            if(prop in appState){
                console.log('application state from this :',appState);
                if(prop === 'currentUser' && val !== null){
                    appState['authorized'] = true;
                }
                else{
                    appState['authorized'] = false;
                }
                appState[prop] = val;
                console.log('application state changed to :',appState);
            }
            else{
                throw new Error('no appState property matched.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

when a user logs in, that information gets matched with a set of all the registered users like so:

```
    collections.users.fetch().done(function () {

                     for (var i = 0; i < collections.users.models.length; i++) {

                            if (user.username === collections.users.models[i].get('username')) {

                            appState.set('currentUser', collections.users.models[i]);
                             break;
                                 }

                          }

                         if (appState.get('currentUser') == null) {
                                throw new Error('null or undefined currentUser');
                           }
                         else {

                           Backbone.Events.trigger('bootRouter', 'home');
                          }
                   });
```

am I doing something wrong, or does JavaScript not allow me to do what I want to do out of the box? I'd rather not have to handle a Backbone.Collection 'destroy' event, but maybe there's nothing else I can do.

So yes, the rather verbose and boilerplate way to handle this would be to listen the model 'destroy' event and then set the other reference to null, but this requires a lot more oversight and is more error-prone than hopefully a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is JS's problem. Unless there's some form of observer, you're the one referencing it, and there's no reason it should be cleared unless you clear it.

Comment: Ok, sure, then how can I clear the reference. If two things in JS are referencing the same JS object. One is in an array, the other is in an object. And the reference in the array is removed or set to null, should the reference in the object be null also?

Comment: it could be that Backbone destroy is not actually setting the objects in the array (user models) to null, it is just removing them from the array, I guess

Comment: References are just that: references. Setting one reference to null doesn't affect *other* references.

Comment: damn. thus the mention of functional reactive programming. how can I set all references to null to the same object, if that object becomes null.

Comment: can you programmatically retrieve references in JS?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What language are you coming from where this is possible (not the reference retrieval)? Off the top of my head (e.g., the languages I use frequently) I don't know of any that do what you want without some form of observation or simple programming.

Comment: I would recommend making appState a Backbone.Model - it has get, set and events. How are you clearing the collection? normally you would do `collection.reset()`, this fires a reset event. On that event or a custom one you could do `appState.unset('currentUser')` - I would think the model would be garbage collected then - there are ways to force garbage collection in your browser (it probably won't happen straight away otherwise)

Comment: thanks Dominic do you have a link to the syntax for invoking/"forcing" GC in JS?